# how to add two element of of array in dataweave

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

i have two arrays like below

```
var array1 = [
{
      "marketPlaceName": "A1",
      "article": "XX103030AE1100M",
      "ats_qty": "0",
      "po_date": "20230302"
    }
]

var array2 = [
{
      "marketPlaceName": "A1",
      "article": "XX103030AE1100M",
      "ats_qty": "1",
      "po_date": "20230303"
    },
{
      "marketPlaceName": "A1",
      "article": "XX103030AE1100L",
      "ats_qty": "2",
      "po_date": "20230302"
    }
]
```

i would like to export this result, add "ats_qty" by article, and the po_date should be the max value of this article.

Below is sample  what i expected to export

```
[
{
      "marketPlaceName": "A1",
      "article": "XX103030AE1100M",
      "ats_qty": "1",
      "po_date": "20230303"
    },
{
      "marketPlaceName": "A1",
      "article": "XX103030AE1100L",
      "ats_qty": "2",
      "po_date": "20230302"
    }
]
```

Comment: What about `marketPlaceName`, what if same article has differebt values of `marketPlaceName` in different elements?

Comment: @Harshank Bansal, all article have same marketPlaceName

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`groupBy`](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dw-core-functions-groupby) to group using the article.
After grouping you will get a result as on object that will look something like this

```json
{
  "article_1_id": [{..all objects related to that article}],
  "article_2_id": [{..all objects related to that article}],
  ...
}
```

You can then [`pluck`](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dw-core-functions-pluck) this to map to the required format. You can tell we need pluck as you want to convert this object into an array, and the array would have same number of elements as the unique articles (i.e. same number of elements as the number of entries in the group by output)

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
(payload.array1 ++ payload.array2) groupBy $.article
    pluck ((groupedValues) -> {
        marketPlaceName: groupedValues[0].marketPlaceName,
        article: groupedValues[0].article,
        ats_qty: sum(groupedValues.ats_qty map $ as Number) as String,
        po_date: max(groupedValues.po_date) // will work since your date string is in yyyyMMdd format. otherwise you need to convert it to a date instance.
    })
```

Comment: Add `as String` to the end of the `ats_qty` expression to convert it back to String as in the expected result.